# React Mouse event not working on canvas if state variable is passed to the drawing function - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, mouseevent

In my React app, I am trying to draw using mouse events on a grid like structure drawn on a canvas.
The drawing function on canvas gets invoked when a change happens the Editor area beneath it.
I noticed that , if I am passing a state variable to this function, the mouse event is not working.

Below are my sandbox code to demonstrate the problem :

Working example (not passing state variable to paintCanvas function) :
https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-on-canvas-by-mouse-events-editor-154hgs

Non-working example (passing state variable to paintCanvas function) : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/drawing-on-canvas-by-mouse-events-editor-sending-text-to-paintcanvas-pjkbun?file=/src/App.js

I seek help to know why it's not working while passing the state variable and how can I resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can someone pls look into this?